# How to get a variable from another scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

I want to be able to get the `difficulty` from my first scene into my second scene, I've tried looking it up, but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. Unless the scenes are both loaded at the same time (not recommended if the game play doesn't need it, just to get your value).

There are 2 ways that you can do to achieve this:

1. Use a sort of a static handler or manager that is not instantiated or use a static variable inside an instantiated singleton handler or manager
2. Use a "global" game object; well, not technically global, but it's a GO that has `DontDestroyOnLoad()` called on it; then you can access whatever script it has

Of course a combination of the two is often used in the case of singletons. If  you want the simplest possible method, use a static variable. Keep in mind it won't be serialized. So don't expect to use it between game sessions (such as after restarting the game). Also serializing it in a saved game needs manual serialization separate from what `JsonUtility` offers.

This is all generalized talk.

Now, if by "difficulty" you mean you have a start menu and you ask the player how hard they want the game to be and they can choose Easy, Medium or Difficult, then you'll need to save it in a normal public variable of an instantiated Singleton, not static. Why? You'll need to save it, else when the player loads the save, the game won't know the difficulty the player picked the first time. Also keep in mind that the variable needs to be a proper field, not a property. It must **not** be `private` or `protected` and without a `SerializedField` attribute (since it's implicit).

Comment: @StelbertStylton If this is what you want and solved your issue or pointed you in the right direction, please mark it as the correct answer and/or upvote it so that it can help others as well that have a similar issue to yours.